Why am I getting a “binary extension can't be installed” error with LastPass?
I was using LastPass for years.
During past few weeks, I can't get binary extension work on Chrome.
Details:

OS: Windows 11
Chrome: 126.0.6478.127
LastPass extension: 4.131.4

I tried everything: uninstall everything LastPass related, shut down computer, and start from scratch, no dice.
Now, LastPass’s about dialog (in Chrome’s extension):

Shows, that binary component has been installed.
However, when I try to activate fingerprint login:

And when I click on this above circled link, it downloads a LastPass installer (named: LastPassInstaller.exe), and immediately when I run this installer:

So now, it's an endless loop.
What shall I do to enable this fingerprint method? Again, it worked for years, and last few weeks it stopped working. Why?

Try to enable "Native Messaging" without the settings for the LastPass browser extension. I can't entirely agree that this is a Web Application SE question. Be sure you install LastPass for Windows Desktop

Thanks, tried that, but not working. Desktop app is installed, Native Messaging is enabled. Which site would be more suitable for this question?

I found a solution that worked on my end. Rather than going through the "Multifactor Options" tab under Account Settings, I went through the "Passwordless Options" tab, where you should see a button to "Enable passwordless" on the device you are working on.



There it gave me three options 1) LP Authenticator App, 2) Windows Hello, and 3) USB Security Key" as options.



Clicking on "Set up Windows Hello" (and confirming from there) did the trick on my end. I can now login with my fingerprint reader.

Thank you. I tried that, but it's not sending OTA SMS to my registered phone due to some technical difficulties LastPass team can't handle.
